# Jackson - Custom Serialization of embedded Objects coming from 3-party Library

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind

I am storing my domain class objects into a document database by transforming them into JSON format. Prior to storing, I would like to apply a conversion on all properties of a specific custom type `LocalizedTexts` and store them as entries into a flat `List/Array`.

In order to understand better the requirement, here are the basic classes:

This is the main domain class:

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Article.ArticleBuilderImpl.class)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Article extends AbstractEntityBase {
    
    @NonNull
    UUID id;
    
    @JsonProperty("iNo")
    Integer iNo;
    
    boolean isValid;
    
    @NonNull
    LocalizedTexts designation;
    
    @NonNull
    ReferenceArticleGroup articleGroup;
    
    Integer numberOfDecimalsSalesPrice;
    
    LocalizedTexts touchCaption;
    
    LocalizedTexts printText;
    
    LocalizedTexts productInformation;
    
    @Singular
    List<String> codes;
    ...
}
```

This is the internal LocalizedTexts class:

```
@Builder(builderMethodName = "internalBuilder")
public class LocalizedTexts extends HashMap<Language, String> implements EntityBase {

    public LocalizedTexts() {

    }

    public LocalizedTexts(Map map) {
        putAll(map);
    }
}
```

and finally, the `Language` enum type:

```
public enum Language {
    AA("aa"),
    AB("ab"),
    AE("ae"),
    AF("af"),
    AK("ak"),
    ...
}
```

**Note** that `Language` and `LocalizedTexts` are being imported from **another library**, so I have no access in order to alter them.

The standard Jackson object mapper produces a JSON file with the following structure:

```
{
    "id": "57bf6daf-4993-4c55-9b19-db6b3d5c9527",
    "iNo": 3,
    "isValid": true,
    "designation": {
        "de": "designation3DE localized designation3 designation",
        "en": "designation3EN localized designation3 designation"
    },
    "articleGroup": {
        "id": "8f6627b8-31d4-4e44-9374-6069571489f7",
        "type": "ArticleGroup"
      },
    "numberOfDecimalsSalesPrice": 2,
    "touchCaption": {
        "de": "touchCaption3DE localized touchCaption3 touchCaption",
        "en": "touchCaption3EN localized touchCaption3 touchCaption"
      },
    "printText": {
        "de": "printText3DE localized printText3 printText",
        "en": "printText3EN localized printText3 printText"
    },
    "productInformation": {
        "de": "productInformation3DE localized productInformation3 productInformation",
        "en": "productInformation3EN localized productInformation3 productInformation",
        "es": "productInformation3ES localized productInformation3 productInformation"
    },
    "codes": [
        "1231231231234",
        "2345678901234",
        "9999999999999",
        "1111111111111"
    ],
    ...
}
```

I would like to serialize my object into a json with this format:

```
{
    "id": "57bf6daf-4993-4c55-9b19-db6b3d5c9527",
    "iNo": 3,
    "isValid": true,
    "articleGroup": {
        "id": "8f6627b8-31d4-4e44-9374-6069571489f7",
        "type": "ArticleGroup"
    },
    "numberOfDecimalsSalesPrice": 2,
    "codes": [
        "1231231231234",
        "2345678901234",
        "9999999999999",
        "1111111111111"
    ],
    "translation": [
        {
            "productInformation": "productInformation3DE localized productInformation3 productInformation",
            "language": "german"
        },
        {
            "productInformation": "productInformation3EN localized productInformation3 productInformation",
            "language": "english"
        },
        {
            "productInformation": "productInformation3ES localized productInformation3 productInformation",
            "language": "spanish"
        },
        {
            "touchCaption": "touchCaption3DE localized touchCaption3 touchCaption Bildbeschriftung",
            "language": "german"
        },
        {
            "touchCaption": "touchCaption3EN localized touchCaption3 touchCaption Caption",
            "language": "english"
        },
        {
            "designation": "designation3DE localized designation3 designation",
            "language": "german"
        },
        {
            "designation": "designation3EN localized designation3 designation",
            "language": "english"
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

So I want to extract all the pairs of LocalizedTexts entries and add them into a single array as show above. When reading back from the database I would like to implement the opposite transformation and deserialize the json above into my original domain class.

I guess I should implement a custom serializer/deserializer and register it into my `ObjectMapper` for 'Article' class as described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization#bd-overview) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization).

As far as I can understand I should use reflection for that purpose but maybe this is going to be an overkill. Any other ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You could JsonIgnore the original properties and annotate a getter `getTranslation' that returns a List of suitable Objects

Comment: I have no access to the original domain classes (which are final)

Comment: Oh, you should make this clear in your question

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I should implement a custom serializer/deserializer

Sure, you can implement a custom Serializer by extending abstract class `StdSerializer` and providing implementation of its `serialize()` method. But it would require a lot of low-level code and wouldn't be flexible.

Another option is to create a so-called [`Converter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/Converter.html) for the `Article` type and provide it through the `converter` attribute of the [`@JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) annotation. Here's a quote from the documentation explaining the purpose of Converter:

> Which helper object is to be used to convert type into something that Jackson knows how to serialize; either because base type cannot be serialized easily, or just to alter serialization.

In other words the goal of Converter is turn the base type into another type which is easier to serialize. Whilst the purpose of Serializer is to instruct Jackson via `JsonGenerator` how to generate JSON from the given object (*which is not very handy when a complex object graph, and a lot of alternations needs to be done*). That's how you can distinguish between the two.

To create a custom Converter for the `Article` type we need to extend abstract class [`StdConverter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/StdConverter.html) and override its `convert()` method, would expect an instance of `Article` and return an object of a different which can be smoothly deserialized. So, firstly, let's create this type that stores the data from the fields of type `LocalizedTexts` structured as required.

Let's call this type `ArticleWrapper`:

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class ArticleWrapper {
    @NonNull
    private UUID id;
    @JsonProperty("iNo")
    private Integer iNo;
    private boolean isValid;
    @NonNull
    private ReferenceArticleGroup articleGroup;
    private Integer numberOfDecimalsSalesPrice;
    @Singular
    private List<String> codes;
    
    private List<LanguageAttribute> translation; // all the data from LocalizedTexts is being stored here
}
```

It also requires a custom type called `LanguageAttribute` to represent pieces of information like `"{ "productInformation":"...", "language":"english" }"`. I've defined it as a [Java 16 `record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/records.html) (*you can reimplement it as a plain `class` as well*):

```
public record LanguageAttribute(
    @JsonAnyGetter
    Map<String, String> map,
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonSerialize(converter = LanguageConverter.class)
    Language language) {}
```

***Note:** that* `LanguageAttribute` has a field of type* `Map`*. It's a single-entry map which is meant to represent properties that vary like* `"productInformation":"..."`, `"designation":"..."`*, etc. and it's annotated with* `@JsonAnyGetter` *because we don't want the property* `"map"` *to be present in the resulting JSON (only its contents is needed). Another option (which some people might find more intuitive) is* `@JsonUnwrapped`*, but it **wouldn't** work here because of this well-known [**documented issue**](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/171) which at the time of writing is still not resolved.*

Here's a minimalistic converter to get the `Language` enum serialized as its lowercased attribute (***note:** change the method used to access the lowercase language name to the proper one*):

```
public class LanguageConverter extends StdConverter<Language, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(Language language) {
        return language.getLangName(); // use the proper method here to access the lowercase enum property
    }
}
```

Finally, here's an implementation of the Converter for the `Article` type, it's a little bit more involved, since this Converter performs more transformations, but it's maintainable and can be changed/extended as needed:

```
public class ArticleConverter extends StdConverter<Article, ArticleWrapper> {
    public ArticleConverter() throws JsonProcessingException {
    }

    @Override
    public ArticleWrapper convert(Article article) {
        
        List<LanguageAttribute> translations = getTranslations(article);
        
        return ArticleWrapper.builder()
            .id(article.getId())
            .iNo(article.getINo())
            .isValid(article.isValid())
            .articleGroup(article.getArticleGroup())
            .numberOfDecimalsSalesPrice(article.getNumberOfDecimalsSalesPrice())
            .translation(translations)
            .build();
    }
    
    private List<LanguageAttribute> getTranslations(Article article) {
        
        return Stream.of(
                toLanguageAttribute(article.getDesignation(), "designation"),
                toLanguageAttribute(article.getTouchCaption(), "touchCaption"),
                toLanguageAttribute(article.getPrintText(), "printText"),
                toLanguageAttribute(article.getProductInformation(), "productInformation")
            )
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .toList();
    }
    
    private Stream<LanguageAttribute> toLanguageAttribute(LocalizedTexts texts, String attribute) {
        return texts.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new LanguageAttribute(
                Map.of(attribute, entry.getValue()), entry.getKey())
            );
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:**

- I've **tested** the solution presented above to make sure that produces the required shape of JSON, but since the information is not 100% percent complete a plain copy-pasting might not work, most likely some changes would be required.

If the process of **deserialization** needs to be customizes as well, I'm leaving it for OP/reader as practical exercise.